# How to transform a list of data into a table on Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a table by using App Script, but I am not good enough to create a table below in App Script.Can someone guide me thru how to create this table?

Most important part is that data will be added every month, which means I am trying to have a script that will detect the row and update, instead of going back and forth every month to update.

This is how I want the  Car Table looks like on Google Sheet:

Note:
Row 1: Automobile will be displayed in a merged call, from A1:C1
Row 2: Make will be displayed in a merged cell, from B2:C2
Row 3: "Honda" will be in A3,   "Audi" will be in B3,    "Lexus" will be in C3
Row 5: A blank row with no data
Row 6: Price will be displayed in a merged cell, from A6:C6

```
     Automobile             
        Make        
Honda   Audi    Lexus
 100     150     200
        
        Price       
 20      30       40
```

Here is the rawData:
Honda   100
Audi    150
Lexus   200
Price   20K
Price   30K
Price   40K

I have set the maximum column to maxCol=3, and I am thinking to use ForEach and Map method so that it can detect the next item and setValue in the next row.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var carTable = "Car Table";
var rawData = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
var carTable = ss.getSheetByName("Car Table");

var header=["Automobile", "Make", "Honda", "Audi", "Lexus", "Price"];

function carTable() {
    maxColumn=3
    var data = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:C" + sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
}
```

Comment: merged cells causes troubles which are not encouraged to use, and the data format you are looking for are not usually considered as a 'table', since table should have one line of headers representing what is inside that column. Also the way you var you headers doesn't make any sense in code principle for Apps-script. In apps-script, an array should always be one row of data.

Answer (score -1):

only to answer the part about how to set values into a spreadsheet in the format you are looking for:

```js
const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheetName = "You sheet name";
const ts = sss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // 'ts' for 'target sheet'
const values = [ // values must be a 2D array, which each inner array is one row, and each value of a row is the cell of each column.
  ["Automobile","",""], // for merged cells, the value to be shown is always the one in the top left corner.
  ["Make","",""],
  ["Honda","Audi","Lexus"],
  [100,150,200],
  ["","",""],
  ["Price","",""],
  [20,30,40],
]
const rowsToMerge = [1,2,6];

for (const row of rowsToMerge) ts.getRange(row,3).mergeAcross();
ts.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
```